# Query not working as expected in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Below is my stored procedure:

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspApprovalHistory]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
                @empID int = null
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @SRFTable table
        (SRFID nvarchar(50))
        declare @currSRFID nvarchar(50) = null
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        insert into @SRFTable
        Select distinct MasterCode from CallForwarding 
        Where EmployeeNo = @empID or ApproverNo = @empID;
        Select *  From callforwarding 
        Where  Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
              and ApproverNo = @empID
              and ForwardDate in (Select max(ForwardDate) from CallForwarding
                              where Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
                              and ApproverNo = @empID)
    END
```

Why it is not working as expected ? It is only returning a single row, on the basis of max forward date in the whole table.

What i want is all the rows where SRFID = Mastercode and ForwardDate = Max(ForwardDate). There are multiple records against a single SRFID and there are multiple SRFIDs. I want all the rows with the SRFIDs where forwarded date is the recent one. So the end result would be rows equal to SRFIDs which are forwarded recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
Select *  From callforwarding 
Where  Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
    and ApproverNo = @empID
    and ForwardDate in 
               (Select max(ForwardDate) from CallForwarding
                where Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
                and ApproverNo = @empID
                group by Mastercode)
```

Comment: A single group by and whole world is changed! Thanks working as expected.

Comment: My guess is that this not the correct answer. In case same dates exist for different master codes, this can return several different forward dates for the same master code. See example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8be2/3

Comment: You are right, but not in my case. Dates against a single ID will always be different pal.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this is what you actually want:

```
Select *  
From Callforwarding c1
Where  Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
and ApproverNo = @empID
and ForwardDate in 
(
    Select max(c2.ForwardDate) 
    from CallForwarding c2
    where c2.Mastercode = c1.MasterCode
    and ApproverNo = @empID
)
```

This way the maximum date is selected only from that particular Mastercode, not from all of them.

Other alternative how to do this is using row number:

```
select * from (
  select
    Mastercode,
    ForwardDate,
    row_number() over (
      partition by MasterCode order by ForwardDate desc) as RN
  from
    Callforwarding
  where
    Mastercode in (select SRFID from @SRFTable)
    and ApproverNo = @empID
) TMP where RN = 1
```

Examples in SQL Fiddle: [Group by](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8be2/2) and [Row Number](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8be2/4)